# Why is the rendering of ui::Text components which use UTF-8 strings being limited when I run my cocos2dx game on an android device?

Tags: android, c++, utf-8, java-native-interface, cocos2d-x

I'm developing a game in C++ on the cocos2dx game engine. I've mostly been testing it on the win32 platform but recently tried it out on android. When I did I found things were not running as expected. In case you're wondering, I'm running the apk on Android Oreo (8.0.0) on a Samsung Galaxy S7.

The first thing I noticed is that some components which were rendered on win32 weren't being rendered on android.

I'm trying to gain a better understanding of why that is but after a few days of digging through online help boards, source code and tutorials I haven't found anything particularly promising.

Here's an example of an issue:

I have a cocos2d::Scene which has a number of ui::Text components which display some text. If the ui::Text components are initialised without any UTF-8 characters, they appear to be rendered without issue.

However, if they are initialised with UTF-8 characters, some will be rendered and some won't. Even after running the adb with the jni debugger, I haven't found any helpful error messages and the program continues to run.

Here's some sample code:

```
using namespace cocos2d;

Scene* MainMenuScene::createScene()
{
    return MainMenuScene::create();
}

bool MainMenuScene::init()
{
    if ( !Scene::init() )
    {
        return false;
    }

 auto visibleSize = Director::getInstance()->getVisibleSize();

    auto ichi = ui::Text::create(u8"一", "fonts/rounded-mgenplus-1c-black.ttf", 24);
    auto ni = ui::Text::create(u8"二", "fonts/rounded-mgenplus-1c-black.ttf", 24);
    auto san = ui::Text::create(u8"三", "fonts/rounded-mgenplus-1c-black.ttf", 24);
    auto yon = ui::Text::create(u8"四", "fonts/rounded-mgenplus-1c-black.ttf", 24);
    auto go = ui::Text::create(u8"五", "fonts/rounded-mgenplus-1c-black.ttf", 24);
    auto roku = ui::Text::create(u8"六", "fonts/rounded-mgenplus-1c-black.ttf", 24);
    auto nana = ui::Text::create(u8"七", "fonts/rounded-mgenplus-1c-black.ttf", 24);
    auto hachi = ui::Text::create(u8"八", "fonts/rounded-mgenplus-1c-black.ttf", 24);
    auto kyuu = ui::Text::create(u8"九", "fonts/rounded-mgenplus-1c-black.ttf", 24);

    auto ichi_h = ui::Text::create(u8"いち", "fonts/rounded-mgenplus-1c-black.ttf", 24);
    auto ni_h = ui::Text::create(u8"に", "fonts/rounded-mgenplus-1c-black.ttf", 24);
    auto san_h = ui::Text::create(u8"さん", "fonts/rounded-mgenplus-1c-black.ttf", 24);
    auto yon_h = ui::Text::create(u8"よん", "fonts/rounded-mgenplus-1c-black.ttf", 24);
    auto go_h = ui::Text::create(u8"ご", "fonts/rounded-mgenplus-1c-black.ttf", 24);
    auto roku_h = ui::Text::create(u8"ろく", "fonts/rounded-mgenplus-1c-black.ttf", 24);
    auto nana_h = ui::Text::create(u8"なな", "fonts/rounded-mgenplus-1c-black.ttf", 24);
    auto hachi_h = ui::Text::create(u8"はち", "fonts/rounded-mgenplus-1c-black.ttf", 24);
    auto kyuu_h = ui::Text::create(u8"きゅう", "fonts/rounded-mgenplus-1c-black.ttf", 24);


    auto ichi_k = ui::Text::create(u8"イチ", "fonts/rounded-mgenplus-1c-black.ttf", 24);
    auto ni_k = ui::Text::create(u8"ニ", "fonts/rounded-mgenplus-1c-black.ttf", 24);
    auto san_k = ui::Text::create(u8"サン", "fonts/rounded-mgenplus-1c-black.ttf", 24);
    auto yon_k = ui::Text::create(u8"ヨン", "fonts/rounded-mgenplus-1c-black.ttf", 24);
    auto go_k = ui::Text::create(u8"ゴ", "fonts/rounded-mgenplus-1c-black.ttf", 24);
    auto roku_k = ui::Text::create(u8"ロク", "fonts/rounded-mgenplus-1c-black.ttf", 24);
    auto nana_k = ui::Text::create(u8"ナナ", "fonts/rounded-mgenplus-1c-black.ttf", 24);
    auto hachi_k = ui::Text::create(u8"ハチ", "fonts/rounded-mgenplus-1c-black.ttf", 24);
    auto kyuu_k = ui::Text::create(u8"キュウ", "fonts/rounded-mgenplus-1c-black.ttf", 24);

    auto layout = ui::Layout::create();
    layout->setLayoutType(ui::Layout::Type::HORIZONTAL);
    layout->setPosition(Vec2(0, visibleSize.height));

    auto layout_kan = ui::Layout::create();
    layout_kan->setLayoutType(ui::Layout::Type::VERTICAL);
    layout_kan->setContentSize(Size(2 * kyuu_h->getContentSize().width, visibleSize.height));

    auto layout_h = ui::Layout::create();
    layout_h->setLayoutType(ui::Layout::Type::VERTICAL);
    layout_h->setContentSize(Size(2 * kyuu_h->getContentSize().width, visibleSize.height));

    auto layout_k = ui::Layout::create();
    layout_k->setLayoutType(ui::Layout::Type::VERTICAL);
    layout_k->setContentSize(Size(2 * kyuu_h->getContentSize().width, visibleSize.height));


    layout_kan->addChild(ichi);
    layout_kan->addChild(ni);
    layout_kan->addChild(san);
    layout_kan->addChild(yon);
    layout_kan->addChild(go);
    layout_kan->addChild(roku);
    layout_kan->addChild(nana);
    layout_kan->addChild(hachi);
    layout_kan->addChild(kyuu);

    layout_h->addChild(ichi_h);
    layout_h->addChild(ni_h);
    layout_h->addChild(san_h);
    layout_h->addChild(yon_h);
    layout_h->addChild(go_h);
    layout_h->addChild(roku_h);
    layout_h->addChild(nana_h);
    layout_h->addChild(hachi_h);
    layout_h->addChild(kyuu_h);

    layout_k->addChild(ichi_k);
    layout_k->addChild(ni_k);
    layout_k->addChild(san_k);
    layout_k->addChild(yon_k);
    layout_k->addChild(go_k);
    layout_k->addChild(roku_k);
    layout_k->addChild(nana_k);
    layout_k->addChild(hachi_k);
    layout_k->addChild(kyuu_k);

    layout->addChild(layout_kan);
    layout->addChild(layout_h);
    layout->addChild(layout_k);

    this->addChild(layout);

    return true;
}
```

Here's what that looks like on win32:

[image: win32 test]

Here's what that looks like on android:

[image: android test]

The order of instantiation of the ui::Text components appears to affect how many of them are rendered and prioritisation for rendering appears to depend on the order of instantiation. However, occassionally a later instantiated ui::Text will be displayed when those instantiated before it aren't.

Here's what happened when I instantiated the same ui::Text components in the following order:

```
    auto ichi = ui::Text::create(u8"一", "fonts/rounded-mgenplus-1c-black.ttf", 24);
    auto ni = ui::Text::create(u8"二", "fonts/rounded-mgenplus-1c-black.ttf", 24);
    auto san = ui::Text::create(u8"三", "fonts/rounded-mgenplus-1c-black.ttf", 24);
    auto yon = ui::Text::create(u8"四", "fonts/rounded-mgenplus-1c-black.ttf", 24);
    auto go = ui::Text::create(u8"五", "fonts/rounded-mgenplus-1c-black.ttf", 24);
    auto roku = ui::Text::create(u8"六", "fonts/rounded-mgenplus-1c-black.ttf", 24);
    auto nana = ui::Text::create(u8"七", "fonts/rounded-mgenplus-1c-black.ttf", 24);
    auto hachi = ui::Text::create(u8"八", "fonts/rounded-mgenplus-1c-black.ttf", 24);
    auto kyuu = ui::Text::create(u8"九", "fonts/rounded-mgenplus-1c-black.ttf", 24);

    auto ichi_k = ui::Text::create(u8"イチ", "fonts/rounded-mgenplus-1c-black.ttf", 24);
    auto ni_k = ui::Text::create(u8"ニ", "fonts/rounded-mgenplus-1c-black.ttf", 24);
    auto san_k = ui::Text::create(u8"サン", "fonts/rounded-mgenplus-1c-black.ttf", 24);
    auto yon_k = ui::Text::create(u8"ヨン", "fonts/rounded-mgenplus-1c-black.ttf", 24);
    auto go_k = ui::Text::create(u8"ゴ", "fonts/rounded-mgenplus-1c-black.ttf", 24);
    auto roku_k = ui::Text::create(u8"ロク", "fonts/rounded-mgenplus-1c-black.ttf", 24);
    auto nana_k = ui::Text::create(u8"ナナ", "fonts/rounded-mgenplus-1c-black.ttf", 24);
    auto hachi_k = ui::Text::create(u8"ハチ", "fonts/rounded-mgenplus-1c-black.ttf", 24);
    auto kyuu_k = ui::Text::create(u8"キュウ", "fonts/rounded-mgenplus-1c-black.ttf", 24);

    auto ichi_h = ui::Text::create(u8"いち", "fonts/rounded-mgenplus-1c-black.ttf", 24);
    auto ni_h = ui::Text::create(u8"に", "fonts/rounded-mgenplus-1c-black.ttf", 24);
    auto san_h = ui::Text::create(u8"さん", "fonts/rounded-mgenplus-1c-black.ttf", 24);
    auto yon_h = ui::Text::create(u8"よん", "fonts/rounded-mgenplus-1c-black.ttf", 24);
    auto go_h = ui::Text::create(u8"ご", "fonts/rounded-mgenplus-1c-black.ttf", 24);
    auto roku_h = ui::Text::create(u8"ろく", "fonts/rounded-mgenplus-1c-black.ttf", 24);
    auto nana_h = ui::Text::create(u8"なな", "fonts/rounded-mgenplus-1c-black.ttf", 24);
    auto hachi_h = ui::Text::create(u8"はち", "fonts/rounded-mgenplus-1c-black.ttf", 24);
    auto kyuu_h = ui::Text::create(u8"きゅう", "fonts/rounded-mgenplus-1c-black.ttf", 24);
```

Here's what that looks like on android:

[image: android test 2]

Other potentially relevant information:

- Increasing the amount of other ui components appears to decrease the
  amount of UTF-8 initialised ui::Text components which are rendered.
- The ui:Text components which are rendered and those which aren't
  appears to remain consistent for a set block of code. In other words,
  the GUI output doesn't seem to vary with the same code on different
  runs.
- ui::Text components which don't use UTF-8 strings seem not to be
  affected and are always displayed.
- Removing the u8 prefix from the strings gives the same results on
  android (missing components but those which are rendered are shown as
  expected) and leads to characters being represented by ???'s on
  win32.
- When I compile on win32 there is no such issue and all ui::Text
  components are displayed regardless of which character set is used.
- I'm specifically using Japanese characters (including kanji, hiragana
  and katakana) but presumably this is an issue for all UTF-8
  characters.

I would like to know why this is happening and what I can do to circumvent it without resorting to hacks.

I will continue to look further into the documentation and source code to try and better understand the root of the issue, but I get the sense that this might be something to do with Android's guarded internals. Ahem.

So far I've been reading through android's documentation on the JNI, NDK and OpenGL and worming my way through all the potentially relevant cocos2dx and android classes I can. I also read through the sections of C++ programming pertaining to strings and locales but it doesn't seem like there's much I'd be able to do without bypassing the cocos2dx framework.

I wonder if the issue might be caused by some JNI restriction or buffering bug. Or perhaps it's something to do with versioning or hardware. Maybe it's something to do with the app being run in debug mode? Also I'm aware that Java uses UTF-16 for its strings internally so I suppose that could also be throwing a spanner in the works somewhere...

Comment: https://github.com/cocos2d/cocos2d-x/issues/20622 Link to Github issue

Answer (score 0):

This issue appears to have stemmed from a couple of bugs in the Cocos2dx game engine. Please see the Github issue posted in the comments for fixes.